# What's ExtendedMessage on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, discord, discord.js

I'm on v12 and after a lot of time I decided to start coding again but I ran into a problem I can't quite fix. At start I wanted to add a function to the `Message` class like so

```js
Discord.Message.prototype.no = function(content){
  this.channel.send(`:x: - ${content}`)
};
```

But after a while I saw that some messages I sent did not have this function and threw me an error `msg.no is not a function`
I used `console.log` to see what didn't have the function and it wasn't a `Message`, it was a `ExtendedMessage` class.

[image]

My question is, what's ExtendedMessage ? I found nothing about it on the documentation and when searching for it on google, I only found things related to inline replies etc.. Discord don't have a class `ExtendedMessage`

I tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling everything again but it didn't help.

My dependecies :

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@blad3mak3r/reddit-memes": "^0.2.5",
    "color": "^4.0.1",
    "discord-buttons": "^4.0.0",
    "discord.bio": "^10.1.2",
    "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
    "easier-pokemon": "^1.0.7",
    "easy-json-database": "^1.5.0",
    "figlet": "^1.5.2",
    "genshin": "^1.2.4",
    "imgur-api.js": "^2.10.6",
    "mal-scraper": "^2.11.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nekos.life": "^2.0.7",
    "node": "^14.17.3",
    "node-osu": "^2.2.1",
    "node-spotify-api": "^1.1.1",
    "node.js": "^0.0.1-security",
    "tiktok-scraper": "^1.4.36",
    "twitch-api-v5": "^2.0.4",
    "user-instagram": "^3.0.0",
    "ytsearcher": "^1.2.4"
  }
```

Comment: Are you using any other node modules?

Comment: @MrMythical Yeah, want me to add my dependecies on the question ?

Comment: Yes, that would helpful. I have a suspicion...

Comment: In general, adding methods to objects by modifying their prototypes will make your code harder to maintain. A `function sendNo(channel, content) { ... }` would probably be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `discord-buttons` package uses `ExtendedMessage` to extend the `Message` class. You can see [here](https://github.com/discord-buttons/discord-buttons/blob/main/src/v12/Classes/Message.js#L7). That's why in the console it shows up like that. Additionally, arrow functions don't have their own `this`. You need to use the `function` keyword to bind `this`.

This worked for me

```js
Discord.Message.prototype.no = function(content) {
  this.channel.send(`:x: - ${content}`)
}
```

Comment: Omg so it was discord-buttons, tysm <3

Comment: @MalikLahlou No problem. Also a note, you should avoid saying "thank you" in the comments on Stack Overflow. That's what the upvote button and checkmark are for ;)